# Oracle Apex 19.1 Cannot Export Application wwv_flow.accept.html

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an application I would like to move to Test. I have navigated to Export (going through the Application Builder -> App -> Export).

I choose Runtime Only. All others are defaults.

Instead of asking where to save the f100.sql file I get "wwv_flow.accept.html" in the dialog box.

If I save this and open it the error seems to be:

`ERR-7620 Could not determine workspace for application ().`

I am connecting over a VPN into the database. Would this have any effect on things?

Is there a general cause for this behaviour? I have exported this application before into a Build environment.

ETA - Even if I choose Build and Runtime option I get the same.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear - did you manage to export the application at all, and get a f100.sql file?
If you did, have you tried importing the application into the development environment?

Answer (score 1):

When importing an application through command-line or SQL Developer, you should meet two terms:

1. You need to have a workspace set in the testing environment (say TEST_WS), and get connected to it

   ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = TEST_WS;
2. You need to run this snippet to adjust the different workspace name:

   BEGIN
       apex_application_install.Set_workspace('TEST_WS'); 
       apex_application_install.generate_offset;
       apex_application_install.Set_schema('TEST_WS'); 
       apex_application_install.Set_application_alias('TEST_F100');
   END;

also, when exporting the application you can alter "Owner Override" to the schema name in the destination pdb